# How to do this with Ajax / Laravel (change the query at the click of a link)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am faced with a problem that I can not solve (I can not even figure out how to do it).

I have four links :

[image]

By default, when we arrive on the page, we have all the data (link all).
I have created a "load more" button to load more data at the bottom of the page.

What I would like is when I click on "3D" or "WEB", it makes me an AJAX query based on a SQL query, or something like that, in my controller so that I can retrieve data that I want.

**Here is my controller :**

```
public function indexGraduated(Request $request)
{
    $students = Student::orderBy('year', 'desc')->inRandomOrder()->paginate(12);

    if($request->ajax())
    {
        return [
            'students' => view('ajax.graduate',
                [
                    'students' => $students,
                    'orientations' => $this->getOrientation()
                ])->render(),
            'next_page' => $students->nextPageUrl()
        ];
    }

    return view('pages.graduate', [
        'students' => $students,
        'orientations' => $this->getOrientation()
    ]);
}
```

**Here is my ajax code :**

```
$.ajax({
  url: page,
    beforeSend: function () {
      button.addClass('loading');
     },
     success: function (data) {
      $('.container').append(data.students);
      button.attr('href', data.next_page);
      button.removeClass('loading');
      },
     })
```

What is the right way to do this?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to have a hidden field on the page and set its value according to the link selected.

On the view page, keep a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="filter" id="filter" value="all">
```

Define the 4 links like so,

```
<a href="javascript:setFilter('all');">All</a>
<a href="javascript:setFilter('3d');">3D</a>
<a href="javascript:setFilter('2d');">2D</a>
<a href="javascript:setFilter('web');">Web</a>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFilter(f) {
        switch (f) {
            // all
            case 'all':
                document.getElementById('filter').value = 'all';
                break;

            case '2d':
                document.getElementById('filter').value = '2d';
                break;
            // and so on
        }
    }
</script>
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: the_url,
    data: {
        input: $('#filter').val();,
   },
  ...
```

Now in the controller, get the value of `input`, and return records accordingly.